# Adding and removing events handlers to html elemts

Tags: jquery

My page consist of menu and body and both of them has div. When page opens I add to div elements event handler using "on" method and everything works fine. But body can be reloaded using ajax. I understand that div at body doesn't work and I want to add event handler to it.
I trying several thing but main problem is that when I add event handler to div it also added to div element at my menu. and when I click at menus div event fires two times. I trying use such construction

```
$('.div-element').off().on('click', function(){///});
```

but this has not any effect.
Please advice something.

Comment: Better would be to use delegation

Comment: ^^ what he said -> `$(document).on('click', '.div-element', function(){///});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click','.div-element', function(){///});
```

Give a shot

Answer (score 0):

Since the `body` is reloaded using `ajax` to make sure you retain the `events` you attached to `div's` inside `body`, you should use `jQuery's` [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/). For example :

```
$('body').on('click', 'div', function(event){
//code for event handler
})
```

This will make sure that `events` added to `div's` are retained even after `body` reload.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click','.div-element', function(){///});
```